# Ruby on rails: Does each work for a looping through empty arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I keep getting the error undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass on line 14. Here is the code in question.

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Comments</h2>

    <% @micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <p>
        <b>Commenter:</b>
        <%= comment.commenter %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <b>Comment:</b>
        <%= comment.body %>
      </p>
    <% end %>


  <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
  <%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

It acts as if you cant call the loop through an array of comments because it is empty. I tried adding <% if @micropost.comments.any? $> on line 13 so that it wouldn't try the loop if there were no comments but then I get the exact same error on line 13. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 4):

replace `@micropost` with `micropost`

Comment: apneadiving is correct, you are mixing @micropost with micropost, which are two totally different variables.

To answer your title question, yes you can loop through an empty array, try it out in irb:

    `[].each {|item| puts item}   #=> []`

Comment: Doesnt that go agains section 7.4 of this tutorial? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. When I do that I get this error  on line 14: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.micropost_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."micropost_id" = 2

Comment: @BigBoy1337: I guess we are inside a partial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes each iterates through an empty array too, it just won't really "iterate" because it is empty.